# Speed issue when using ReadFile to read COM/Serial port

Tags: c++

I have a C++ application that sends and receives data through a com port.  There is a function that reads a port in a for loop 60 times for a specific delay because we are using TAP protocol .

```
    for( i = 0, bPerformRead = true; i < nRepeatCount; )
    {
       //m_hCom is HANDLE to the COM port.
       if( ReadFile(m_hCom, p, nNumBytes ? 1 : nWaitStrLen/*sizeof(szBuf)-nNumBytes*/,&dwBytes, &ov) == FALSE )
       {
         //Do some logics
       }

       //sleep for 33 ms
     }
```

I run this application on my test laptop which is virtual COM and this would take around 2 seconds (33ms * 60) equals 1980ms

However, when we run this on one of the client machine who uses USB to Serial and this step would take up to 17 seconds.

After much troubleshooting I pin point it down to this ReadFile(), i think it takes almost 10 times as long to complete on the client machine versus mine.

Do you know if this issue specific to the port settings? I tried to have exactly the same port setting and mine machine still only takes 2 seconds..

Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm kind of hitting the wall on this one.

I also have the setting on the Read interval on the serial port.

```
        Timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = MAXDWORD; 
    Timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0; 
            Timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
    Timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
    Timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;

            SetCommTimeouts( m_hCom, &Timeouts )
```

[image]

Comment: Not related, but why don't you use QtSerialPort?

Comment: Oh this is one of the legacy dll piece in our software so I don't really have any choice :)

Comment: I do notice one thing though, on the machine that is slow, the Timeout is set to ON while the other has Timeout set to OFF... though I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it